# How can I fetch all open cases and change the case owner

Tags: salesforce

we have to write a code to Fetch all "Customer - Direct" type accounts and get all its open cases and Change the owners for all these open cases.

Comment: What have you tried so far, what do you struggle with

Comment: I am not sure about this like I can get all open cases but not sure how to change the owners of these cases, can you please help me in this

Comment: Community here reacts very poorly to low effort questions. we're not a free code writing service, especially when it looks like an interview question and there's just a requirement, with zero attempts to solve it from your side

Answer (score 0):

You don't need code for this, there's perfectly fine setup -> transfer utility to find & change owners. Or run a report, change it in excel, use import wizard back?

```apex
List<Case> cases = [SELECT Id, Account.OwnerId
    FROM Case 
    WHERE IsClosed = false AND Account.Type = 'Customer - Direct'];
for(Case c : cases){
    c.OwnerId = c.Account.OwnerId; // I don't know what you want to do,
    // you can hardcode specific user's '005...' id here too
}
update cases;
```